# Decompose a finite (not necessarily positive) measure $\nu$ into two mutually singular measures $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, manifolds, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $\nu$ be a non-zero finite (not necessarily positive) measure on a compact Kähler surface $M$.

Is it always possible to decompose the measure $\nu$ as follows $\nu=\lambda_1-\lambda_2$?

Where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are (non-zero) finite positive measures that, in addition, are mutually singular.

You can take a look at the screenshot taken from "*Harmonic Currents of Finite Energy and Laminations*", J. E. Fornaess and N. Sibony, Page $980$, Proof of Lemma $3.1$.

(We decompose the measure $c(\alpha) \nu(\alpha)$ on the space of plaques, $c(\alpha) \nu(\alpha)=\lambda_1 - \lambda_2$ for positive mutually singular measures $\lambda_j$).

[image]

Comment: For example $\lambda_1=\mu$ and $\lambda_2=0.$ Perhaps you meant $\mu$ to be a signed measure.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc non-zero

Comment: If $\lambda_2$ is nonzero, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are mutually singular, then $\lambda_1  -\lambda_2$ is not a positive measure.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I edited the question. Could you please, if you don't mind of course, take a look again?